# Is the converse of "a Lipschitz function must be continuous" true?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

The converse of that statement is: A continuous function must be a Lipschitz. Which I think is false.

I either wanted to use contradiction or a counterexample.
But I get stuck either way.

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) for plenty of examples.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is not Lipshitz. $x^2$ on $[0,+\infty)$ is not Lipschitz. For "nice" functions, a function is Lipschitz if its derivative is bounded.

Comment: Notice also that $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is even _uniformly_ continuous, but not Lipschitz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false, every Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous but not every continuous function is uniformly continuous. Take $f:\mathbb R \to[0,\infty)$ where $f(x)=x^2$, this function is not uniformly continuous and so not Lipschitz, but it is continuous everywhere!

Comment: My problem comes from not being able to show that f(x) = x^2 is not a Lipschitz function. How would I use the definition of Lipschitz to show that x^2 is not?

Comment: So we need $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|$ for some $M \in \mathbb R$ If you let the domain be compact then it's clear that on $[a,b]$, $|x^2-y^2| = |x+y||x-y| \leq 2(b-a)|x-y|$ so it would be Lipschitz, however if you unbound the domain you have $|x^2-y^2|=|x+y||x-y|$ where $|x+y|$ can get as arbitrarily large as you'd like, therefore there's no $M$ that satisfies this!